# Convert dataframe to 5*5 grid of choice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Following are the standard values for score and grades.
Score column contains numbers within specified range.

| Score | Grade1 | Grade2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <260 | A1 | IA1 | D1 | ID1 |
| 260-275 | A2 | IA2 | D2 | ID2 |
| 275-280 | A3 | IA3 | D3 | ID3 |
| 280-285 | A4 | IA4 | D4 | ID4 |
| >=285 | A5 | IA5 | D5 | ID5 |

Input :-

| Score | Grade1 | Grade2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 290 | A1 | IA4 | D3 | ID2 |

Output:-

| Tiers | Grade | Grade1 | Grade2 | Grade3 | Grade4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  | ID2 |
| 3 |  |  |  | D3 |  |
| 4 |  |  | IA4 |  |  |
| 5 | 290 |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
data1 = {'Grade': {0: 'B1', 1: 'B2', 2: 'B3', 3: 'B4', 4: 'B5'},
         'Grade1': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'A3', 3: 'A4', 4: 'A5'},
         'Grade2': {0: 'IA1', 1: 'IA2', 2: 'IA3', 3: 'IA4', 4: 'IA5'},
         'Grade3': {0: 'D1', 1: 'D2', 2: 'D3', 3: 'D4', 4: 'D5'},
         'Grade4': {0: 'ID1', 1: 'ID2', 2: 'ID3', 3: 'ID4', 4: 'ID5'}}
data2 = {'Grade': {0: 'B5'}, 'Grade1': {0: 'A1'}, 'Grade2': {0: 'IA4'},
         'Grade3': {0: 'D3'}, 'Grade4': {0: 'ID2'}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**Code**

make condition by using `broadcasting`

```
df1[df1.eq(df2.iloc[0])]
```

result:

```
    Grade   Grade1  Grade2  Grade3  Grade4
0   NaN     A1      NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ID2
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     D3      NaN
3   NaN     NaN     IA4     NaN     NaN
4   B5      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: very neat and clean approach. +1 for that.

Comment: I updated the question by adding scores in range of numbers. So, how can we do in such case?